# Django shell like functionality for asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently building an asp.net core web app (webapi 2.0) and I am looking to add some backend shell functionality similar to Django's. Is there anything similar to the Django shell for a C# asp.net web application? Would be willing to consider switching frameworks if it was still C#.

Comment: did you find anything?